# How to insert a filter in Data Studio with one selection at time?

Tags: filter, data-visualization, looker-studio

I've inserted a filter control in my report, but I would like that the viewers with the link could only check one element at time and not multiple dimensions.

Is it possible? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found out. In the "Style" section it is possible to check for single selection.